# Flutter lottie animation not showing correctly

Tags: flutter, animation, lottie

I have this lottie animation:

https://lottiefiles.com/71783-rope-skipping-lemon

But when I try to add it to my flutter app (I show the network version, but Lottie.asset did not work either) the result is different:

Some part of the animation is missing:

[image]

How can I resolve that?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure in your pubspec.yml you have

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - lib/assets/annimations/
```

Then download the annimation from lottie and put it into annimations folder.
After taht you can use it like this:

```
Lottie.asset('lib/assets/annimations/rope-skipping lemon.json')
```

Then

```
flutter clean && flutter pub get
```

And relaunch your app. It should work

Comment: Yes, I did exactly like that, but not working.
I just showed the network version in an online Flutter IDE, still not working, but it should, you can see on the gif the incorrect animation.

Comment: Did you try with a different animation ?

Comment: other animation works properly, this one (the rope) is not moving.

Comment: It may be an issue with the animation then, use another one instead

Comment: As mentioned in this link (https://github.com/xvrh/lottie-flutter/issues/275#issuecomment-1506511113) if the animation uses expressions then it is not supported.